# How do i iterate through this arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm relatively new to programming. I'm trying to teach myself Java, and I'm messing around with `ArrayLists`. How do I go about printing each of these strings individually? Right now, I have it where it prints each list, but I want to be able to work with each string individually. Like if I wanted to print out the length of each string using a for loop how would I do that? I tried doing the standard for loop, but I couldn't figure out what to put for the termination requirement. I tried `i < 2` since `test[3]` is length 2, but that gave an out of bounds error since the other test lists only have one element.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int arrlen = 4;
  ArrayList[] test = new ArrayList[arrlen];

  for(int i=0; i<arrlen; i++)
  {
    test[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  test[0].add("zero");
  test[1].add("one");
  test[2].add("two");
  test[3].add("three");
  test[3].add("second three");


  for(ArrayList i : test)
  {
    System.out.println(i);
  }

}
```

Comment: Since array start at 0 and go to length -1 you need to loop until length -1. So 3 for this examples

Comment: you don't need to have `Array` of `ArrayList` if you are storing one value to each. and you need nested for loop as you have `Array` of an `ArrayList`

Comment: @Prashant OP is *not* storing one value to each. OP is adding *two* strings to the last (4th, index 3) `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Andreas ok, I didn't noticed index of last value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
  for(ArrayList<String> arrayList : test)
  {
    for(String s: arrayList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
```

Or,

```
  for(ArrayList<String> arrayList : test)
  {
    for(int t = 0; t < arrayList.size(); t++) {
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(t));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using `i` to represent a `List<String>` is *very* confusing.

Comment: I used the variable as mentioned in question

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying to implement nested arraylist if you are here is the way

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

    inner.add(100);     
    inner.add(200);
    outer.add(inner); // add first list
    inner = new ArrayList<Integer>(inner); // create a new inner list that has the same content as  
                                           // the original inner list
    outer.add(inner); // add second list

    outer.get(0).add(300); // changes only the first inner list

    System.out.println(outer);
```

Answer (score -4):

Below should help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(3);
        test.add(4);
        test.add(5);

        //USING FOR EACH LOOP:
        for (Integer i : test) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        //USING FOR LOOP:
        for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(test.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't fit what question is doing. Notice that *two* strings are added to the 4th (index 3) `ArrayList`. The resulting array is `[[zero], [one], [two], [three, second three]]`.